# ie8 errors with positioning and z-index

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, z-index, css-position

i have a content-box, where i want to display 2 background-images within and content laying over. the following code is working in ff, chrome and ie9, but not in ie9 with compatibility and ie8.

```
#content {
background-color: #dcdde1;
position: relative;
min-height: 347px;
}

#content_box {
z-index: 3;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 848px;
padding: 20px;
}

#content_background_top {
background-image: url('../img/content_background_top.png');
background-repeat: repeat-x;
position: absolute;
height: 146px;
width: 888px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 2;
}

#content_background_bottom {
background-image: url('../img/content_background_bottom.png');
background-repeat: repeat-x;
position: absolute;
height: 215px;
width: 888px;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1;
}

<div id="content">
    <div id="content_background_top"></div>
    <div id="content_background_bottom"></div>
    <div id="content_box">
        <?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
        <?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

pls help, its very important to make this working in

greet
M.

Comment: what do you mean 'doesn't work' ? link to fiddle or working example would be great...

Answer (score 0):

oh, wait. try:

```
#content {
background-color: #dcdde1;
position: relative;
min-height: 347px;
height: 347px;
}
```

If this doesn't work, you migh need clearfix.